# Magento – Programmatically reorder multiple orders by cronjob

Tags: magento-1.6

I would like to programmatically reorder specific orders by cronjob and send an order confirmation by mail. I have a simple php file in my root directory which is triggered by a cronjob every once in a while:

```
<?php
include_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

//some existing order ids
$orderIds= array('911', '1106', '926');

foreach($orderIds as $orderId){
    Mage::unregister('rule_data');
    Mage::getModel('adminhtml/session_quote')
        ->clear();

    /* @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order */
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId)
        ->setReordered(true);

    /* @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote */
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
        ->setStoreId($order->getStoreId())
        ->assignCustomer(Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId()))
        ->setUseOldShippingMethod(true);

    /* @var Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create $model */
    $model = Mage::getModel('adminhtml/sales_order_create')
        ->initFromOrder($order)
        ->setQuote($quote);

    /* @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $newOrder */
    $newOrder = $model->createOrder();
    $newOrder->setQuoteId($quote->getId())
        ->sendNewOrderEmail();

    $model->getSession()
        ->clear();
}
```

It seems to work so far, new orders are placed and the emails are sent. But the problem I experienced is that the customer in the new orders is always the one from the first old order (in this case the order with the id 911). Of course, this also affects the order confirmation emails, so they're all sent to the same email address... Also, the order items seem to add up in the cart, so the last order which is reordered contains all the order items of the previous orders... What am I doing wrong?

I appreciate every help I can get! Thank you!

Comment: To make it clear: What I want is to create new orders from existing orders by their id. The new orders need to contain all the information the old ones had (Items, Customer, Shipping Information etc.). Unfortunately Magento keeps the Customer information while looping through the order IDs, so the emails are all sent to the customer of the first order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You are calling `Mage::getModel('adminhtml/session_quote')->clear()`,
   which gets a new instance of the session and tries to clear that.
   But the `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create` class gets the
   session by using   `Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')`,
   which always gets the same instance from the Magento registry. So
   you are trying to clear another session instance.
2. Even if you would try to clear the right session instance from the
   Magento registry by using:
   `Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->clear()`, there would
   still be a problem. As the `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Session_Quote` class
   doesn't define this method, it ultimately calls
   `Varien_Object->unsetData()`, which only does this: `$this->_data = array();`

   But the information in the `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Session_Quote` class
   is stored in the `$_quote`, `$_customer`, `$_store` and `$_order` properties,
   so they don't actually get cleared, but persist.

I solved the problem by deleting the `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Session_Quote` instance in Magento registry before each of the orders, so that it needs to create a new one for each order.

Just add this at the beginning of the loop:

```
Mage::unregister('_singleton/adminhtml/session_quote');
```

Cheers! ;)

Comment: Thanks man, that helped me a lot!!! As soon as I get some reputation, you'll get an upvote ;)